# conemu pass env var to WSL bash terminal

Tags: environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux, conemu

I'm trying to get a task defined in ConEmu to run multiple instance of Ubuntu bash using the WSL layer of Windows 10.

I followed the examples to set up a task to split the UI the way I want, and that part works great.  My problem is that I'm trying to use environment variables to pass through commands to run after logging in, and I want different things to run in each panel.

Here is the task command I'm using:

set "STARTUP_CMD='gfp && make server' " & set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl -cur_console:p -cur_console:d:C:\xxx\yyy

On the Linux side I have code in my ~/.bash_aliases file that looks for the STARTUP_CMD env var and tries to execute it.  I found code that can pull env vars from the Windows side, which is where the 'set' commands appear to be storing things.  Problem is, Windows doesn't know what to do with these, and it tries to expand them when they are read, so it all blows up.

I had this working before, but had to wipe and rebuild my machine recently, and unfortunately didn't have the working command backed up anywhere.

I thought this was the recommended way to run bash with WSL, but I would rather have a way to send stuff directly to the Linux layer as env vars (or if someone has a better way to queue up different commands for each pane, I'm all for that too).  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh course I find the answer right after posting the question...  posting here to help others that hit the same issue (or my future self if I forget and have to wipe my machine again).

set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl **-eSTARTUP_CMD="gfp && make server"** -cur_console:p -cur_console:d:C:\xxx\yyy

You just have to prefix the env var you want with -e and pass it as a param to conemu-cyg.  It goes through without any modification on the Windows side and you can read it just like any other env var on the Linux side.